# Merge two tables (Full Outer Join) but get additional rows (PowerQuery)

Tags: merge, powerquery, full-outer-join

I want to join two tables with 3 merging columns.

Here is the first table:
[image]

Here the second table:
[image]

That´s what I get:
[image]

I want to get all rows from the Table "IST" as well as all rows from Table "SOLL". Every time when there is data in one of each tables, I want to get just null values.
PowerQuery just adds arbitrarily new rows, which aren´t in the original tables.

I just used "Merged Queries as New" and used as matching columns "CC", "Date", "Block/Day".

Code:
= Table.NestedJoin(#"SOLL", {"CC", "Date", "Block/Day"}, #"IST", {"CC", "Date", "Block/Day"}, "IST", JoinKind.FullOuter)

I expect the following after Expanding:
[image]

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are getting `Block 5`, `Block 6` etc... since they are not even in your tables.

I suspect you are using SQL and Query Folding may be messing this up. See if `Table.Buffer(...)` fixes it up for you. Try:

```
Table.NestedJoin(
  Table.Buffer(#"SOLL"), {"CC", "Date", "Block/Day"},
  Table.Buffer(#"IST"), {"CC", "Date", "Block/Day"},
  "IST", JoinKind.FullOuter
)
```

You could also add `Table.Buffer(#"the last step")` at the end of each query.

Comment: Yes, I use SQL. THANKS A LOT! That worked!

Answer (score 0):

You want to start the merge in IST and use

```
  #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"CC", "Date", "Block/Day"}, SOL, {"CC", "Date", "Block/Day"}, "SOL", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
  #"Expanded SOL" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "SOL", {"CC", "Date", "Number", "Pieces", "Block/Day"}, {"SOL.CC", "SOL.Date", "SOL.Number", "SOL.Pieces", "SOL.Block/Day"})
```

[image]

Comment: It is also possible that table "SOLL" includes more data. So LeftOuter or RightOuter are no options! I need FullOuterJoin